# Phonegap CLI 5.1.1 --variable doesn't show up in plugin.xml

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, plist, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to grab a variable and use it in my plugin.xml to build URL Types. Every times I build, I check my .plist file. It spits out the $URL_SCHEME instead of the actual value. Here's my code,

```
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="CFBundleURLTypes">
  <array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>MY_SCHEME</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>$MY_SCHEME</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
</config-file>
```

I added my plugin using,

```
cordova plugin add ../myplugin/ --variable MY_SCHEME=myScheme
```

Any idea why "myScheme" doesn't show up on my .plist file, but instead it shows "$MY_SCHEME" ?

Edit July 27, 2015:
Here is my plugin.xml - http://pastebin.com/YH7LzTjf

Comment: Can you share your plugin.xml? Or the part of it responsible for the variable?

Comment: Turns out, not only the CLI that got problem. I uploaded my plugin, and use Phonegap Build config file to change the variable. It still doesn't take it. @MaciekCzarnik I updated my question with my plugin.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `<preference/>` to make `--variable` work. Try this:

```
    <preference name='MY_SCHEME'/>
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="CFBundleURLTypes">
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                <string>MY_SCHEME</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>$MY_SCHEME</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </config-file>
```

I don't know - for some reason I'm unable to add it with `CFBundleURLTypes` as a parent (although it's fine for some other strings), but it might be something wrong with my Cordova.